# Parse a JSON (array with tabs and arrays) with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, tabs

I have been trying to parse a JSON response since few days without success.
    I've read on the internet and this site how to parse with a foreach but I think            the structure of json is too different from the examples I've found.
    So here is the JSON:

```
 array(1) 

        { ["matches"]=> array(10) 
            { [0]=> array(13) { ["matchId"]=> int(2125878813) 
                                ["region"]=> string(3) "EUW" 
                                ["platformId"]=> string(4) "EUW1" 
                                ["matchMode"]=> string(7) "CLASSIC" 
                                ["matchType"]=> string(12) "MATCHED_GAME" 
                                ["matchCreation"]=> float(1432656547642) 
                                ["matchDuration"]=> int(1852) 
                                ["queueType"]=> string(15) "RANKED_SOLO_5x5" 
                                ["mapId"]=> int(11) 
                                ["season"]=> string(10) "SEASON2015" 
                                ["matchVersion"]=> string(9) "5.9.0.318" 
                                ["participants"]=> array(1) 
                                    { [0]=> array(10) { 
                                    ["teamId"]=> int(200) 
                                    ["spell1Id"]=> int(7) 
                                    ["spell2Id"]=> int(4) 
                                    ["championId"]=> int(67) 
                                    ["highestAchievedSeasonTier"]=> string(8) "PLATINUM" 
                                    ["timeline"]=> array(9) 
                                        { ["creepsPerMinDeltas"]=> array(3) 
                                            { ["zeroToTen"]=> float(6.2) 
                                              ["tenToTwenty"]=> float(7.4) 
                                              ["twentyToThirty"]=> float(4.4) } 
                                              ["xpPerMinDeltas"]=> array(3) 
                                                { ["zeroToTen"]=> float(336.2) 
                                                  ["tenToTwenty"]=> float(428.3) 
                                                  ["twentyToThirty"]=> float(396) } 
                                                    ["goldPerMinDeltas"]=> array(3) { 
                                                    ["zeroToTen"]=> float(270.7) 
                                                    ["tenToTwenty"]=> float(363.6) 
                                                    ["twentyToThirty"]=> float(294.8) }
```

If I understand well this is an array with tabs inside and arrays also ?

> I would like for example to display the 10 matches id :
>   matches->matchId
>       matches->participants->championId
>       matches->participants->timeline->creepsPerMinDeltas->zeroToTen

Here is what I've done so far to display the `matchId` :

```
 $decodeHisto = json_decode ($resultHisto,true);

    //var_dump($decodeHisto);       
    foreach ($decodeHisto{[matches]} as $d)      
    {

    echo $d->{[matchId]}-;

    }
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: JSON is a well defined format. Your example above is _not_ JSON format. This looks more like a dump of an associative array by means of `var_dump()`...

Comment: i think it is `preg_match()`'s matches

Comment: @Viral then it would contain the original subject as first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not JSON, as JSON is exactly defined like this:

```
{
"Herausgeber": "Xema",
  "Nummer": "1234-5678-9012-3456",
  "Deckung": 2e+6,
  "Waehrung": "EURO",
  "Inhaber": {
    "Name": "Mustermann",
    "Vorname": "Max",
    "maennlich": true,
    "Hobbys": [ "Reiten", "Golfen", "Lesen" ],
    "Alter": 42,
    "Kinder": [],
    "Partner": null
  }
}
```

You can convert a JSON array to PHP with this code:

```
$array = json_decode($json);
```

But as I said before, your code is not JSON. It seems to be even a PHP array. Then you can access with:

```
$arr["matches"][0]["matchId"]
```

for example.

Comment: This requires to have access to the array itself. I suspect the OP has a dump of the array instead, so a string.

Comment: Use `eval` :-D Or `serialize` before and `unserialize` after.

Comment: `eval()` is something you really _never_ should use :-) Apart from that it only works with the output of `var_export()`, not `var_dump()`... And again: serialization requires the array, which I doubt is available...

Comment: @arkascha: See the smiley behind `eval` :-)

Comment: I did, I just spun further your joke... Didn't you see the one behind my statement about `eval()`?

Comment: @Msing: You can mark my answer as solution if you want so.

Answer (score 0):

Given the additional information you provided by posting an own "answer" to your question here I would like to point out this:

So if what you posted in your question is a dump of the result you got back from a call to `json_decode()`, then what you have simply is an array. An associative, multi level array, but still just a normal php array. This is also what the documentation of the `json_decode()` function clearly states: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

There is absolutely no reason to somehow "parse" an array. The "tabs" or whitespaces you can see in the dump are *not* part of the result you have, so of the array. Those are artefacts by the dumoing function you use to visualize the array. You can simply access all members (or members of members...) of the array sirectly by their associative "path", as you will see in all examples of php code you can find on google. Here an example:

```
$value = $decodedJson['matches'][0]['matchDuration'];
```

Given `$decodedJson` is the result array as posted in your question, then `$value` will now hold the integer value 1852.

You can access whatever part or element of the array you like. you can iterate over parts of the array using php's iteration constructs like `foreach` and the like. You can search in the array by means of php's array functions(http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: Ok thank you. Then i'll browse your links and will try to get the value that i want.